# Why does pushing an element into a new Array returned by a concat( ) return the size of the array instead of the array itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, chain

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var a = ['a','b'];
var b = ['c','d'];
var c = a.concat(b).push('e');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This will lead to the number '5', instead of ['a','b','c','d','e']

Comment: First sentence of the documentation: "[The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by why...since that's what the documentation specifies

Comment: Read the documentation of the method before asking questions about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push Hint: Google search "javascript Array push MDN"

Comment: If you want the last value back, use the resulting length as part of the look up. Of course, this could be a little confusing for others when reading your code: `var val = arr[arr.push("val")-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method returns the new `length` property of the object upon which the method is called.

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

Here,

```
a.concat(b) //returns an `array`. But wait, the statement still has a method chained,
            //and to be evaluated.
(returned array).push('e'); // the chained push() is invoked on the returned array.
```

which in turn returns the `length` of the newly formed array. 
So the final return value of the statement is the `length` of the array, which is stored in the `c` variable.

To capture the returned `array` by the `concat()` operation, you can modify your code to break down the chained methods into multiple statements, as below:

```
var c = a.concat(b);
c.push('e');
console.log(c) // prints the array content.
```

Comment: @Ja͢ck - Might be the OP was confused with the chained application of the the `concat()` and `push()` methods.

Comment: `the statement has not ended unless a \`;\` is encountered` - [That's not always true with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1903116) ;)